# Why is « allô » written with a circumflex?

Tags: orthographe, diacritiques, emprunts

Often the circumflex indicates that a word used to be spelt with an *s*, but that the *s* has disappeared in the current spelling. According to Wiktionary, *[allô](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all%C3%B4)* comes directly from the English *hello*, so why is it spelt with a circumflex? As far as I know there is no word *allo* spelt without the circumflex, or any other variation in accents.

Comment: [Wikipedia suggests a different origin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/All%C3%B4#Origine_du_mot_.C2.AB_Hallo_.C2.BB) (in French).

Comment: A circumflex accent can be used to suggest a different pronunciation.
In this case I suppose the circumflex accent indicates the o has to be spoken more like in "spoken" and not like in "bother".

Comment: @Yves I think that your comment could be added as an answer

Comment: I didn't even know *allo* could be written with a circumflex.. And I'm french native!

Comment: @Ange-à-Liberté La graphie « allô » est bien antérieure à 2001. Elle a à priori toujours été la plus répandue depuis que ce mot est apparu. La variante sans accent est cependant recommandée depuis la réforme orthographique de 1990.

Comment: @Ange-à-Liberté Le Larousse et l'Académie rapportent et entérinent l'usage plutôt qu'ils ne prescrivent de nouvelles règles, ils ne sont donc pas tenus d'appliquer la réforme. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=allo+!%2Call%C3%B4+!&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1870&year_end=2016&corpus=19&smoothing=5&share=) indique qu'allo est plus courant qu'allô sauf entre 1990 et 2007. En dehors de cette période, allo domine, surtout entre 1910 et 1960. Les accents aigus sur les a et o sont sur des mots anglais et y indiquent une diphtongue.

Comment: @Ange-à-Liberté rectification: les accents sur les o seulement. Aujourd'hui, la graphie *ow* est utilisée pour rendre cette diphtongue.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci, bien intéressant, je ne savais pas que le _ngram_ digérait des requêtes avec accents. Pourquoi la version avec accent a pris son essor au moment de la réforme, à contre-courant ? La notation du TLFi m'a laissé perplexe quand j'ai comparé avec le [NED](https://archive.org/stream/newenglishdict05murrmiss#page/n63/mode/1up). Je ne comprends toujours pas pourquoi on a eu cette graphie avec l'accent, et encore moins pourquoi on l'a toujours dans des ouvrages [du jour](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/allo) près de 30 ans après la réforme. On va finir par savoir. Merci !

Comment: @jlliagre & Ange-à-Liberté Vu les recherches, vous devriez répondre.

Comment: J'ignorais totalement qu'_allo_ peut prendre un accent circonflexe. Mais dès l'instant où la question de son origine est posée, je suis frappé par l'analogie avec _ô_ : seul autre mot français qui me vienne à l'esprit se "terminant" (si l'on peut dire, pour un mot à lettre unique !) par un _o_ affecté d'un circonflexe. Pour lui aussi, CNRTL et le TLFI citent une origine (le _o_ latin) dépourvue de circonflexe, dont on se demande donc comment il a pu venir s'ajouter.

Comment: @YohannV Yves a donné la bonne réponse.

Comment: @jlliagre Même si "Yves a donné la bonne réponse" est précisément adressé à Yohan V, je le prends aussi comme pouvant vouloir répondre à mon propre commentaire/question relatif à l'origine de l'ajout de l'accent. Or je ne suis pas d'accord avec le motif invoqué (indication de la prononciation) : comme l'a fait ensuite remarquer Ange-à-Liberté, _numéro_ se passe de circonflexe, pour une même prononciation. De même pour _lasso_,  _vélo_, _saxo_, _boléro_, _métro_, _dodo_, ...

Comment: @cFreed Il y a aussi rho/rhô pour qui les deux orthographes se rencontrent aussi: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rh%C3%B4 http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rho

Comment: @Ange-à-Liberté Voir [ici](https://books.google.fr/books?id=sns16Kzj3c0C&pg=PA196&lpg=PA196&dq=hall%C3%B3o&source=bl&ots=pCe70g26ac&sig=FKSywRhKnzlpJdALbexjfsW6EN4&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRy6WJqMLQAhUG7RQKHXBdAZYQ6AEIVTAJ#v=onepage&q=hall%C3%B3o&f=false) pour un *hallóo*.

Comment: @Ange-à-Liberté L'accent (ou une apostrophe) indique la diphtongue formée par deux *o* successifs mais c'est vrai que si ce sont les mêmes voyelles, on ne peut plus parler de diphtongue. En anglais, *oo*  se rend par `/ʊ/` (*book*), `/u:/` (*too*) ou `/ɔː/` (*poor*). La graphie *óo* représente à priori plutôt les combinaisons `[ɔʊ]` ou `[oʊ]` voire `[ʊə]`, mais ce ne sont que des hypothèses…

Answer (score 4):

"Allô" is from a word, not an interjection, but it has gained the "^" for the sake of pronunciation. We imagine the voice rising with the "Allô".

- It may sound strange, but indeed, the English "hello" is from... French:

> Quant au 'halloo' anglais, il remonterait à très loin, aux bergers
> normands installés en Angleterre après l'invasion de Guillaume le
> Conquérant au XIe siècle (Lien externe), bergers qui s'appellaient ou
> rassemblaient leurs troupeaux par des 'halloo' (l'anglo-normand
> 'halloer' signifiait "poursuivre en criant"). Plus tard, cette même
> interjection a signifié trois choses : "exciter les chiens à la
> chasse", "exprimer la surprise" et, celle qui nous intéresse, "attirer
> l'attention à distance". Cette dernière utilisation explique que ce
> 'halloo' ait été utilisé au téléphone puis ait traversé l'Atlantique
> avec l'invention.

> Officiellement, c'est en mars 1876 qu'Alexander Graham Bell (Lien
> externe) fait réellement fonctionner son téléphone dans lequel sa
> première phrase a été d'une intensité insoutenable et vraiment digne
> d'une telle première : "Monsieur Watson, veuillez venir dans mon
> bureau, je vous prie".
>
> Le premier central téléphonique à Paris est installé en 1879. Dès
> 1880, la mise en relation entre personnes se fait par des 'hallo'
> venus du 'halloo', salutation prononcée au début des conversations
> dans le pays d'origine du téléphone. Ce 'hallo' perdit ensuite son 'h'
> pour devenir allô ou allo.

Source: http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/allo.php